# How to empty the location.state without using browserHistory(as it is marked unsafe). this.props.location.state value do not reset on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

when you pass data form one route to another using link 
Second View

sendonView rendered successfully and data is available inside this.props.lcoation.state.data but on page refresh its not reset

is their any other way reset without using browser History

Comment: Can you explain that why you should do that?

Comment: Why you don't want uae `history.replace('', null);` or just use redux store that on refresh data clear.

Comment: @MohammadRezaKhedri i should have to do that because i am saving "applied filter list " in this.props.location.state data when redirecting and after page refresh all filter should be clear !! do not want to use history because different browser implements history in different ways also history is mutable The history object is mutable. Therefore it is not recommanded..

Comment: For this case, I suggest you to use `sessionStorage` or if you want use in your app, Use `redux-persist` to handle that with store.